# Create a face model 3d from an image 2d

Tags: python, add-on

I'm new on Python and OpenCV. I want to create an Add-On for Blender which create a 3d model of a face uploading some photos of the face from some different points of view (like the game-face of EA).
Is it possible? Do someone know some tutorials that can help me?